# Error during installing selenium on Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, selenium

**Error: The type or namespace name 'Selenium' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

**CODE Generated by the IDE**

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Threading;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using Selenium;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class Untitled 
{
private ISelenium selenium;
private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.ehow.com/");
selenium.Start();
verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}

[TearDown]
public void TeardownTest()
{
try
{
selenium.Stop();
}
catch (Exception)
{
// Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
}
Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
}

[Test]
public void TheUntitledTest()
{
            selenium.Open("/tips_7490061.html");
            selenium.Click("//a[contains(text(),'How to Conserve Water Usage')]");
            selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the Selenium DLL to the c# project?

I have a basic tutorial available [here](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_csharp_nunit.htm) that should help you through getting started.

Comment: Yes, I have added the following files as references: nunit.framework.dll,nunit.core,Thoughworks.seleniumcore,Thoughtworks.selenium.integrationTests,Thoughtworks.selenium.unitTests

Comment: Yes, I have added the following files as references: nunit.framework.dll,nunit.core,Thoughworks.seleniumcore,Thoughtworks.selenium.in‌​tegrationTests,Thoughtworks.selenium.unitTests